# How to check authentication in nodejs static server

Tags: node.js, express

If have two servers in nodejs one i static server and other is express server(handling api requests).

In static server side i have following routes
`/login`
`/dashboard`
`/payment`

Any one who will login there request will be forwarded to the express server api to check the authentication and if the user is authenticated then response will be true once the response will be true user will be redirected to /dashboard page and can also access /payment page.

But due to no validation on the static server side i cant identify who are authenticated to visit dashboard and payment page and any user will direct enter the url and visit the dashboard and payment page. So how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you need to make the browser understand it is authenticated.
You can achieve this by making use of [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) or cookies.
It is recommended to use existing solutions rather than spawning your own.'

A good option would be [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/).